# Declarar o MAP já passando valores em C++ ?

Tags: c++

**Bom galera, eu vejo que com o array eu posso fazer isso:**

```
int array[]= {5,6,4,2};
```

Minha duvida é, na linguagem **C++** eu consigo declarar o map já passando valores ?

Exemplo:

```
map<string,int> mymap = { "a",1};
```

Comment: Use assim: map<int, char> m = {{1, 'a'}, {3, 'b'}, {5, 'c'}, {7, 'd'}};

Comment: Mas eu quero com string.

Comment: E isso ai nem compila.

Comment: std::map<std::string, int> map = { { "String1", 2 }, { "String2", 4 } };

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na verdade o seu exemplo de inicialização do `map` ficou a um `{}` de ficar certo!

Bastaria apenas:

```
map<string,int> mymap = {{"a",1}};
//                      ^       ^
```

A questão é o que o primeiro par de `{}` representa o `map` inteiro e depois leva outros `{}` para cada elemento inicializado.

Por isso se quisesse inicializar com mais elementos podia fazer:

```
map<string,int> mymap = {{"a",1}, {"b",2}, {"c",3}};
```

Vale ressaltar que o suporte é a partir de C++11

[Documentação](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map)

Comment: Porém, isso só funciona no c++98

Comment: @VictorOCV impossível: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization

Comment: @VictorOCV Muito pelo contrário, o suporte é C++11 para acima. Se for inferior não tem nenhum caminho tão direto.

Comment: Você está errado Isac, é c++98 sim..

Comment: @VictorOCV Você consegue fundamentar a sua afirmação ? É que eu já fundamentei a minha. Se olhar para vários dos links da documentação que foram passados, como [este](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/map) vê escrito no "`map( std::initializer_list<value_type>` ..." numerado como (5) a versão "(since C++11)".